# Populating a dropdown with jquery/json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dropdown

This is my first time requesting assistance (bit of a novice coder still) so please don't hesitate to tell me I'm doing something stupidly.

I've built a JSON file that will have thousands of items and I want to be able to dynamically populate dropdowns on various pages from that file, and later to dynamically populate dropdowns based on prior selections. I researched this to death, but it seems most of the tutorials and questions I found don't seem to work in this particular way. Essentially, I load the page, and the items fail to populate; that is, the dropdowns are empty. Console shows only one error, which according to everything I could find indicates the CDN isn't being loaded. So, here it is:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
     <select id="mainhand"></select>
     <br>
     <select id="offhand"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
                $.getJSON('http://nodtools.net/stats.json', function(obj) {

                            //iterate over the data and append a select option
                            $.each(data.item, function(key, value) {
                                    // set the value of option to each item in the list as you iterate through
                                    var option = $('<option><option/>').val(value.name).text(value.name);
                                    // almost any of them can be added to the main hand
                                    if (value.type == 'slash' || value.type == 'crush' || value.type == 'pierce' || value.type == 'whip' || value.type == 'staff') {
                                        $('#mainhand').append(option);
                                    };
                                    // only shields and 1h weapons can be in off hand
                                    if (value.hands == 1 || value.type == 'shield') {
                                        $('#offhand').append(option);



                                        // continue on for all types: bow, arrow, quiver, etc.
                                        });
                                    });

                            });
                        });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a strong feeling I'm missing something glaringly obvious...if someone could point it out, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: "_I researched this to death, but it seems most of the tutorials and questions I found don't seem to work in this particular way_" - I guess it is because parsing JSON with thousands of items each time you show a dropdown is a very, very bad idea since most of the times, you will probably only need 5 or 10 of the items in the JSON.

Comment: Check that link. I assume that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the specific question or problem?

Comment: You have not indicated what is not working, but you cannot add the same `<option>` to 2 different `<select>`. You need to `.clone()` it.

Comment: That was stupid of me, I've added the specific failure. That link was tremendously helpful, thank you. As for the .clone(), I had no idea, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some code mistakes e.g brackets are on the right place or non necessary brackets:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
                $.getJSON('http://nodtools.net/stats.json', function(obj) {

                            //iterate over the data and append a select option
                            $.each(data.item, function(key, value) {
                                    // set the value of option to each item in the list as you iterate through
                                    var option = $('<option><option/>').val(value.name).text(value.name);
                                    // almost any of them can be added to the main hand
                                    if (value.type == 'slash' || 
                                        value.type == 'crush' ||
                                        value.type == 'pierce' ||
                                        value.type == 'whip' ||
                                        value.type == 'staff') 
                                    {
                                        $('#mainhand').append(option);
                                    }
                                    // only shields and 1h weapons can be in off hand
                                    if (value.hands == 1 || value.type == 'shield') {
                                        $('#offhand').append(option);
                                    }

                                        // continue on for all types: bow, arrow, quiver, etc.
                                        });
                                    });

                            });
```

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3qjf8ob3/2/)
Does it works for you?

Comment: Afraid not. But thank you! It does clear things up a bit and should help quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the JSFiddle provided by Alex Berd that should populate the two dropdowns: [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/csworen/mzpgkccu/)

You can't populate them both (accurately) in the same `$.each(/**/)` block, although I can't tell you definitively why not. I'm sure someone else can clear that up.

The pertinent portion of the code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //iterate over the data and append a select option
    $.each(items, function (key, value) {
    // set the value of option to each item in the list as you iterate through
    var option = $('<option>').val(this.name).text(this.name);
    // almost any of them can be added to the main hand
    if (items.type != 'shield' && items.type != 'bow' /* etc. */) {
        $('#mainhand').append(option);
        }
    })

    //iterate over the data and append a select option
    $.each(items, function (key, value) {
        // set the value of option to each item in the list as you iterate through
        var option = $('<option>').val(this.name).text(this.name);
        // only shields and 1h weapons can be in off hand
        if (this.hands == 1 || this.type == 'shield') {
            $('#offhand').append(option);
        }
    })
    /*
     * continue on for all types: bow, arrow, quiver, etc.
     */
})
```

Now you just need to properly import the .json data.

Thanks,

C§